# Can I move to Germany from the US during COVID?

Tags: germany

A German friend has recommended me for a job in Germany - it sounds like it could work out well, and I feel I would like living in Germany.  The problem - COVID-19.

It's my understanding EU (and thus) German borders are closed to US citizens until the COVID situation is under control.  I also know a German-American (i.e. non-EU citizen) who was turned away at the gate even though her sister was hospitalized.

My German friend has told me as long as I quarantine for 2 weeks after arrival, I will be allowed in.  Both Google and my friend's experience say otherwise.

Is it possible for someone with American citizenship to travel to Germany currently?

EDIT - If I accept the job the company will handle the work visa.  During a normal time, I'd just interview - get an offer and fill out the paperwork.  The issue is would I be allowed to even board the plane and disembark once I'm there?  No one is 100% sure about the answer.

Comment: You mention a job offer, does that come with a work permit and long stay visa?

Comment: @Willeke - Yes.  It's not a question of visa, but if I'd be allowed to board the flight at all.  It's uncharted territory so no one is 100% sure of anything.

Comment: General entry for US residents (not citizens) is not permitted unless certain conditions are fullfilled. Among them is that one has a D-Visa to take up residence. For this, you would have to have a work contract and make an application through a consulate.

Comment: I voted to re-open as this is not a question about living in a foreign country but about whether you can fly there under current restrictions, which makes it a travel question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I accept the job the company will handle the work visa.

If the work permit is granted, the responsible authority will instruct the consulate to issue a D-Visa to take up residence.

With this D-Visa you will be allowed to board the plane and enter the Schengen Area. At present a direct entry to Germany is advised and preparations for a quarantine should be made.

Answer (score 3):

Under normal circumstances, [citizens of the US and some other countries](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/visa/residence-visa/922288) can just fly to Germany and apply for their work permit / residence visa after arrival. With the covid-related travel restrictions, this is currently not possible, and you will have to apply for a German D visa while in the US. You should then be able to use that visa to enter Germany, though you should of course be prepared to comply with quarantine requirements upon arrival.